# Uploading to client iTunes Connect account

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile

I have been contracted to update an app for a client. I was given the project in a `.zip` file (because their old developer left). I successfully fixed the application and now I have to upload it to their iTunes Connect account.

My problem is that in order to add me as a developer to their iTunes Connect, I had to create an Apple ID with an email extension (because iTunes Connect won't let you join multiple teams) e.g. `myname+clientname@gmail.com`.

Now when I try to upload the app, I get an issue that the team identifier on my distribution provisioning profile is not the same as the team identifier of my iTunes Connect account.

How do I do this? It seems like a normal thing for freelance developers to have to do, so there must be a way to create a provisioning profile with the right team ID prefix for uploading the app.

Also, I am using my own developer center account for which I already have a linked personal iTunes Connect account.

Comment: You probably added your provisioning profile to run the app on your iPhone or something similar to that. Check all your dependencies / usages in Xcode.

Comment: provisioning profile should be same, both in the app created on iTunesConnect and in the project. And it should be distribution.